# Does changing aws lambda consumer batch size of kinesis cause data loss or duplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have an existing `kinesis` stream and multiple `lambda` consumers with different batch sizes. I want to update one of the lambda's batch size(from 25 to 1000). Since `edit` option is not available, I think there are two options(afaik);

First one is;

- disable the kinesis from lambda console.
- create a new kinesis trigger, set batch size
- delete the disabled one.

Second option;

- delete the existing kinesis from lambda console
- create a new kinesis trigger, set batch size

My questions are;

- What is the best practice among those options, are there any better options ?
- Will there be any data loss/duplication in either of these scenarios?
- How can i prevent data loss or data duplication if there is a possibility?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the CLI for [update-event-source-mapping](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/update-event-source-mapping.html).

Using the option `--batch-size` you can update proposed batch size.

An example of this would be running

`aws lambda update-event-source-mapping --uuid  "a1b2c3d4-5678-90ab-cdef-11111EXAMPLE" --batch-size 8`

To run this you will need the UUID, this can be retrieve via the [list-event-source-mappings](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/list-event-source-mappings.html) command. Specifying the function name of the Lambda as an argument will provide you with the triggers.

By doing this there should be no data loss, and it can be scripted so it is easy to rollback.

Comment: Thank for your reply it is really comprehensive, didn't know there was an edit option.

Comment: With AWS normally it’s possible via CLI, even if not visible in console